# Retrieve all values Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to retrieve all values for 'des' from termL list. It contains string value.

Sample data

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5d19fbc0e4b0490ed4c5a02d'), 'uID': '2004', 'documentTitle': 'Training the trainers','termL': [{'code': '30', 'des': 'SVM'}, {'code': '50', 'des': 'NN'}]}
```

Mongo query

```
record = mycollection.find({}, {
    "uID":1,
    "documentTitle": 1,    
    "indexTermList": {'$elemMatch':{'des':1}}
}).limit(1)
```

Comment: What's the expected output ?

Comment: Something like {'des':['SVM','NN']}. The des field should contain all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator and the dot notation to reshape your data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            uID: 1,
            documentTitle: 1,
            des: "$termL.des"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iloHbuTpdkJ)

Comment: Thanks. How can I limit the number of results

Comment: @joel use $limit as the next statement (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)